# Sending ROOT Histograms over MPI

Tags: c++, mpi, root-framework

I think this begs the more general question.
Suppose I have a custom class with dynamically allocated memory inside. 
Having done copy and swap and all that stuff to avoid memory leaks inside one processor. Is there any way to send and receive that class over MPI?
(I'm not sure which one should be the title. Someone experienced please help me on the title)

But to my specific case.
This is my code.
Here the object event. the data i need. the function event loop processes it and fills the histogram e2. I pass taskid and numtasks to the functions because based on that it creates an histogram for different sections of data. I want to all it all together in the end.

```
int main(){
  MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
  int taskid,numtasks;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);

  //Irrelevant
  .
  .

   TH1F* e2 = new TH1F("e2","e2 Title",50,0,14);
   dataevents::event t;
   EventLoop(t,e2,a,taskid,numtasks);
   //a is somewhere in the irrelavent code don't mind. e2 gets filled inside the EventLoop function.
   if(taskid != MASTER_MPI){
     MPI_Send(e2,e2->Sizeof(),MPI_BYTE,MASTER_MPI,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   }
   if(taskid == MASTER_MPI){
     TH1F* e2_main = new TH1F("e2","e2 Title",50,0,14);
     TCanvas *c1= new TCanvas("c1","e2",600,400);
     e2_main = e2;
     for(int k=1;k<numtasks;k++){

       TH1F* e2_temp =new TH1F("e2","e2 Title",50,0,14);
```

I think this is where my mistake is. I'm now sure how to initialize the buffer memory for receiving.
I tried Malloc, I tried MPI_Buffer Attach. Nothing seems to work.

Rest of the code:

```
           MPI_Recv(e2_temp,e2_main->Sizeof(),MPI_BYTE,k,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
           std::cout<<" This could be the error";
           e2_main-> Add (e2_main,e2_temp,1,1);
         }
    //Master Specific code.. Irrelevant
       } 
      MPI_Finalize();
    }
```

Comment: do yourself a favour and dont use ROOT histograms for anything else than plotting data.

Comment: I don't. The function just fills up the histogram nothing else.

Comment: I dont understand. You dont display the histogram using multiple processors. What i mean is use a `std::vector` or anything else to collect the data and only when you want to display it on the screen use a ROOT histogram

Comment: after all it is just a wrapper around an array, and to my experience it is not a very convenient one when you need anything but viewing the data on a screen

Comment: The data I have is huge. I didn't want to save it. Wanted to add the details to the histogram and immediately forget it.

Comment: erm... you "save" it in a root histogram. A root histgoram is, as I said, just a wrapper around an array that stores the data, though not a lightweight one, so actually you will use less memory if you use e.g a `std::vector`

Comment: I agree. If things don't work out. I might have to write a small histogram class which bins accordingly.

Comment: a histogramming class is only a couple of lines of code if you use a `std::map`

Comment: But still my first question remains. In general how would you pass such variables over mpi?

Comment: just dont allocate it dynamically, its some time ago that I used MPI, but it should be possible to find general examples

Comment: Yeah.. I would go that as the last resort but it more of a general curiosity now to see if it is possible!

Comment: why last resort? Dynamically allocating stuff should be your last resort. One reason I dislike root histogram is that they make you think it would be good to allocate them dynamically everywhere

Comment: Incase I need the root histogram for analysis in future. I don't know why. But using the root file seems to be standard in my college for Particle physics. So my only other option is to write a vector class myself and then convert to root later. But even that requires passing it via mpi and that brings back to the same question!

Comment: But thanks. I just saw that there are others posts which talk about passing vectors. I think I'll do that.